# Is there a bug in Chrome with justify-content: space-between and min-height?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

Here is code I working on:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: #cbcbcb;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>should be on the TOP</div>
  <div>should be on the BOTTOM</div>
</div>
```

And I am getting predictable result in  Firefox:

[image]

But in Chrome I am getting next result:

[image]

Why I am getting this space under the bottom element?

It could be fixed by changing css `min-height` to `height`, but in my context it's important to have `min-height` value here.

[Try it in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/86he9jw6/4/)

P.S. This behavior is reproduced only in Chrome and Canary, and seems only on Windows.

My env: Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) and Win 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It certainly looks like a bug.

In any case, you can work around it with an `auto` margin:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: #cbcbcb;
}
.container > div:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>should be on the TOP</div>
  <div>should be on the BOTTOM</div>
</div>
```

Flex `auto` margins are part of the spec and can be used to align flex items.

Full explanation here: [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Comment: Big props for this fix. I am quite interested in understanding why this fixes it.  Why did you try this fix in the first place? It's really not intuitive it should fix the issue.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, flex `auto` margins are a part of the spec. They apply directly to flex items. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I remember that I had similar problem a couple of moths ago. This is because the height is set to auto, try to set another value for height property and the problem will be solved.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;  
    height:0;
    min-height: 150px;
    background-color: #cbcbcb;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div> should be on the TOP</div>
   <div> should be on the BOTTOM</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, seem like a bug in chrome.

Here is an alternate way to get the same result:

1. Use `flex-direction: row` for flex children.
2. Allow wrapping of flex children by enabling `flex-wrap: wrap` and set `flex-basis: 100%` to make them having full width.
3. Set the alignment of last child to the `flex-end`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;    
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: #cbcbcb;    
}
.container div {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.container div:last-child {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div> should be on the TOP</div>
  <div> should be on the BOTTOM</div>
</div>
```